# Как перебрать строку в цикле foreach?

Tags: c#, строки, foreach

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> RomNumber =
    new Dictionary<string, int> {
        { "I", 1 },
        { "IV", 4 },
        { "V", 5 },
        { "IX", 9 },
        { "X", 10 },
        { "XL", 40},
        { "L", 50 },
        { "XC", 90 },
        { "C", 100 },
        { "CD", 400 },
        { "D", 500 },
        { "CM",900 },
        { "M", 1000 }
    };

    public static int Decode(string s)
    {
        int total = 0;
        int prev = 0;
        foreach (string c in s)
        {
            int curr = RomNumber[c];
            total += curr < prev ? -curr : curr;
            prev = curr;
        }
        return total;
    }

}
```

В цикле foreach пишет что тип char невозможно преобразовать в string.
И не пойму, вроде char не юзаю. И как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: `foreach (string c in s)` — что вы тут пытаетесь сделать, при условии, что s — это строка?

Comment: 1. Поменяйте тип словаря на Dictionary<char, int> 2.Уберите из словаря значения, которые вы не используете. 3. Поменяйте двойные кавычки на одинарные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не работает

```csharp
foreach (string c in s)
```

Потому что элемент строки как массива - символ `char`, а не строка.

Попробуйте так

```csharp
foreach (char c in s)
{
    int curr = RomNumber[c.ToString()];
    total += curr < prev ? -curr : curr;
    prev = curr;
}
```

А вообще задача типовая, вот я нагуглил [пример](https://studassistent.ru/charp/perevod-rimskih-chisel-v-arabskie-c) за пару минут.